# How to remove a stripped screw thread from a wooden stool leg

Tags: screws, legs

I have a wooden stool. One of the legs has a stripped screw thread. I want to replace it with another screw, but I'm not sure how to remove the original one.
[image: stripped screw thread]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. It's not totally clear what is going on here, so just to check are these metal threaded inserts that you need to remove to replace with new ones? If these were the thread-in types then removal could be very straightforward, with screw extractors possibly being all you need. But I suspect they could be press-in, so it could be very much more harder, although if you can get a firm grip on the flange with vice grips or a metalworking vice you may be able to work them out. Note this will leave the holes in need of repair/reinforcement before the new inserts go in.

Comment: @Graphus Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, these threaded are stripping and no longer could hold a screw so I need to replace it. Since it seems stuck inside, a little bit hard to just pull it out. I have tried a bit by using a minus screw driver but the metal is too brittle and the head is broken. So the screw extractors you means is something using the driller but a head for extraction purpose?

Comment: If you don't currently have broken-screw extractors you can try other things first. You could just try drilling them out, using a bit that just fits in the hole to start and then slowly going bigger, until there's little metal left which should be easy to pull out with pliers.